# How to detect what class an object is from? Qt

Tags: c++, qt, types, detection

I'm programming a physicssimulation in QT with balls and this is the collision detection I'm using to detect collision between balls.

```
bool Ball:: circCollide(QList <QGraphicsItem *> items) {
    QPointF c1 = mapToScene( this->boundingRect().center());
//    qDebug() << "c1x" << c1.x();
//    qDebug() << "c1y" << c1.y();
//    qDebug() << "Listcount3: " << scene()->collidingItems(this).count();

    foreach (QGraphicsItem * t, items) {
//      qDebug() << "Classname: " << typeid(t).name();
//        if (typeid(t).name() == "Ball")
        if ( t->boundingRect().width()<200)
        {
            double distance = QLineF(c1,mapToScene( t->boundingRect().center())).length();
    //        qDebug() << "tx" << mapToScene(t->boundingRect().center()).x();
    //        qDebug() << "ty" << mapToScene (t->boundingRect().center()).y();
            double radius1 = this->boundingRect().width() / 2;
            double radius2 = t->boundingRect().width() / 2;
            double radii = radius1 + radius2;
    //        qDebug () << "distance radius1: " << radius1;
    //        qDebug () << "distance radius2: " << radius2;
    //        qDebug () << "distance :" << distance;
            if ( distance <= radii )
            {
            //    qDebug() << "true collision";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
 //   qDebug() << "false collision";
    return false;
}
```

Now I have the problem that this sometimes is also called for when they collide with my walls.
The balls have the Class Ball which I made myself and inherits from QGraphicsItem,
while the walls have the class QLineF which also inherits from Qgraphicsitem. Is there any good way to figure out whether an object "t" belongs to the class Ball?
I've already tried

```
typeid(t).name()
```

but that returns the same for both classes (P13QGraphicsItem).

Also the list I feed to at the beginning contains all objects colliding with this item hence I have to feed it a list of QGraphicsItems.

Comment: `QLineF` is an existing Qt class that carries four `qreal` values. It does not derive from `QGraphicsItem`. What is the class of the walls that you speak of? Why can't you use `dynamic_cast` to the derived type and verify that way? Say `dynamic_cast<Ball*>(...)` or `dynamic_cast<Wall*>(...)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try casting similar to this example:

```
Tag* tag = new Tag();
Polygon* polygon = new Polygon();
Polygon* polygon_cast = dynamic_cast<Polygon*>(polygon);
if(polygon_cast) qDebug() << "Cool!";
else qDebug() << "oh..";
Tag* tag_cast = dynamic_cast<Tag*>(tag);
if(tag_cast) qDebug() << "Cool!";
else qDebug() << "oh..";
```

Answer (score 2):

Override [`QGraphicsItem::type`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#Type-varx) in Ball. Return something above the value of `UserType` and then call type on each `QGraphicsItem` to determine if it is a `Ball`.

Answer (score 1):

If `Ball` is derived from `QObject`, and has the `Q_OBJECT` macro in its declaration, you can simply call [`QObject::metaObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#metaObject) and [`QMetaObject::className`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#className):

```
t->metaObject()->className();
```